# Storing the x87 FPU Control Word

Tags: assembly, x86, att, fpu, x87

I'm making a function which returns the FPU Control Word register (16bit).
According to documentation, I have to use `fstcw` and a memory place.

My place in memory is:

```
fpuctl: .word 0
```

And my function is:

```
.global getFPUControlState
    .type getFPUControlState, function
    getFPUControlState:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp 
    xorl %eax, %eax #clear eax (ax too)

    fnstcw fpuctl #store in fpuCTL
    mov fpuctl, %ax #put it in 8bit %ax

    leave
    ret
```

The console says:

> Memory protection violation.

How to use `fnstcw` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL:DR: you probably put `fpuctl: .word 0` in the read-only `.text` section along with your code.  Store to some scratch space on the stack, or to the BSS if you really want to use static storage.

---

You're right, [the only form of  `fnstcw`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/FSTCW:FNSTCW.html) is memory-destination. 
  The more commonly-used `fnstsw %ax` (the x87 *status* word) has an AX-destination form, but `fnstcw` doesn't.

(Of course, x87 is obsolete except when you actually need 80-bit precision; [modern x86 has at least SSE2 so you can and should do scalar FP math in XMM registers](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath#x86note).  The SSE FPU's control and status bits are all in the MXCSR, separate from the x87 control and status.)

Also note that **if you're calling this from C and going to *modify* the x87 control word, you need to tell the compiler about it** so it doesn't assume that the rounding mode is still round-to-nearest, or that the precision is still 80-bit (64-bit mantissa).  This can matter for compile-time constant-propagation, and other optimizations.  For example, gcc has `-frounding-math` and `-fsignaling-nans`.  It may also support C99 `#pragma STDC FENV ACCESS ON`, but I'm not sure gcc or clang are fully standards compliant for that.  See also https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath.  (You should use standard C functions from [`fenv.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv) to modify the FP environment, like `fegetenv` / `fesetenv`.)

If you're going to use this from hand-written asm, make it a macro that takes a 2nd arg as a scratch memory location, instead of a function.  This is too tiny to make sense as a non-inline function; it's 2 useful instructions (`fnstcw` and a reload); the rest is overhead.

---

BTW, AX is a 16-bit register. AL is the low 8 bits of EAX.

Also, `movzwl fpuctl, %eax` would do a zero-extending word load so you wouldn't need to xor-zero eax first.

---

You haven't provided a MCVE, but **probably you put `fpuctl: .word 0` in the read-only `.text` section along with your code,** so you get the same error as if you'd used `mov %eax, getFPUControlState`.

**Instead, put it in the BSS** (zero-init static storage, where the zeros aren't stored in your executable, just a total size).

```
.bss
fpuctl: .zero 2         # 2 bytes of zeros in the BSS

.text                   # switch back to the .text section
.globl getFPUControlState         # GAS does accept .global as a synonym for .globl
.type getFPUControlState, function
getFPUControlState:
       # leave out the EBP stack-frame stuff, you're not using it for anything
    fnstcw   fpuctl
    movzwl   fpuctl, %eax       # zero-extending word load into EAX

    ret
.size getFPUControlState, . - getFPUControlState
```

As an alternative, [use `.lcomm` to reserve 2 bytes in the BSS](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Lcomm.html) and label it with fpuctl as a non-exported label:

```
.lcomm  fpuctl, 2     # puts stuff in the BSS regardless of current section
```

---

#### But really, you don't need static storage at all for this

So you can save yourself a potential page fault by just using the stack.

```
.globl getFPUControlState
.type getFPUControlState, function
getFPUControlState:

    sub      $4, %esp          # reserve space on the stack
    fnstcw   (%esp)
    movzwl   (%esp), %eax
    add      $4, %esp          # restore ESP to point at the return address

    ret
```

Or, if you'd rather optimize for code-size at the cost of a store-forwarding stall from a dword load after a word store:

```
    push     $0
    fnstcw   (%esp)
    pop      %eax         # upper 2 bytes are zero from the PUSHed data
    ret
```